# How to get text after or before certain tags using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an HTML document, something like this:

```
<root><template>title</template>
<h level="3" i="3">Something</h>
<template element="1"><title>test</title></template>
# one
# two
# three
# four
<h level="4" i="5">something1</h>
some random test
<template element="1"><title>test</title></template>
# first
# second
# third
# fourth
<template element="2"><title>testing</title></template>
```

I want to extract:

```
# one
# two 
# three
# four
# first
# second
# third
# fourth
</root>
```

In other words, I want "all text after `<template element="1"><title>test</title></template>` and before the next tag that starts after that."

I can get all text between root using `'//root/text()'` but how do I get all text before and after certain tags?

Comment: I don't think there's a selector for it (i might be wrong of course), maybe you can use a SAX approach

Comment: could you please elaborate on the sax approach?

Comment: sax is a way to navigate the document one tag at a time instead of referencing a specific tag with a selector, but after some research I think you will face the same problem, that is, you can have the root text but not the text between a tag and another, I guess you need to substract all other tags from '//root/text()' or (if you can) change the template format to use somethig like a <p> tag for that intermediate text.

Comment: It's not HTML, it's XML. Also, the sample XML won't validate because your closing `<root>` node is after your example text.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<root>
    <template>title</template>
    <h level="3" i="3">Something</h>
    <template element="1">
        <title>test</title>
    </template>
    # one
    # two
    # three
    # four
    <h level="4" i="5">something1</h>
    some random test
    <template element="1">
        <title>test</title>
    </template>
    # first
    # second
    # third
    # fourth
    <template element="2">
        <title>testing</title>
    </template>
</root>
'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
text = (doc / 'template[@element="1"]').map{ |n| n.next_sibling.text.strip.gsub(/\n  +/, "\n") }
puts text
# >> # one
# >> # two
# >> # three
# >> # four
# >> # first
# >> # second
# >> # third
# >> # fourth
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure krusty.ar is right that there's not a built-in method for achieving this.  You can just remove all the tags inside the root tag one by one if you'd like.  It's a hack, but it works:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) # or Nokogiri::HTML.parse(File.open(file_path))
doc.xpath('//template').remove
doc.xpath('//h').remove
doc
```

That gives the result you're looking for with the HTML you posted.

Comment: This would leave 'some random test' in the middle of the results.